# how to approach making these granules?

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

Ok, so I have to make this product in 3D, Im fine with modeling and texturing the container, what Im not sure of is how to approach the granules inside the container, its almost like a rough sand/ gravel look and feel only its white... any ideas on how to approach this? [image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: maybe you could largely fake it with a texture, and just put some grains on the top? You just need to find a photo that could simulate it (maybe clean up a bit the right photo)

Comment: Expanding on @moonboots comment -   do you have (safe) access to this material, so you can study individual granules, and/or photograph a flat layer of them?

Comment: It is going to end up being a 360 degree turn around of the product, but that seems like a very good idea... Think ill definitely try that. Thanks for that great idea moonboots :)

Comment: I do have safe access to the material... to photograph a picture of a flat layer will definitively be helpful... I think a combination of your suggestions (moonboots and Robin Betts) would get this job done perfectly... Think you guys have solved my problem, thank you so much guys really helpful feedback :)

Comment: Once in Texture Paint mode, use a tool like Stencil with your photo as Texture, I find it very convenient

Comment: Ah yes i didn't think of that, that is brilliant, I havent been in the 3D field for a while and have forgotten about all these tools... another brilliant idea thanx so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found another way to approach this. Using the particle system in blender and using the hair type, I just sampled a granule that I made quickly and emitted it over an object which would have the same shape of the granule inside the bottle.

[image]

As you can see in the image, this seem like a decent approach, I still have to play around with the settings and the texture of the granule but i think it will get the job done nicely :)

Comment: yes, good way to do it, maybe add a bit of powder texture to your granules

Answer (score 1):

Create a cylinder with a bit relief on its top, unwrap it and fake your granules with a texture, also put some grains on the top. You just need to find a good photo for your texture (maybe clean up a bit the right photo). Once in Texture Paint mode, use a tool like Stencil with your photo as Texture, I find it very convenient. Add a Normal or Bump map to improve the 3D simulation.

Comment: If you have the time, patience, and equipment.. you can shoot a true normal map with a procedure like [this one](http://www.zarria.net/nrmphoto/nrmphoto.html)

Comment: This link is actually very helpful, I do have a few programs that can assist me with this. But thank you for the link :)

Comment: You can use the normal and displacement maps from [freely available textures of gravel](https://cc0textures.com/tagged/type:Gravel) if any of them resembles the texture of your granules